# Separating Query Results Into Weeks

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a small website that will track various data and I'm using PHP and MYSQL to do this. What I'm looking to do is have a summary page that separates all of the data into weeks, and it needs to be dynamically created as it is going to continue for quite some time. Any recommendations?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week is a function that you can use to sort / group / filter by.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your data? How is it dynamic? Do you mean the summary must be created on-the-fly? Adding a date created/update field to your data would allow organization by week, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Spin through your MySQL results and populate them into an array of weeks.  Something like this:

```
foreach ( $results as $result){

      $weeks_array[ date("W",  $result['timestamp]')   ][] = $result;
}
```

Then you can spin through each week and spit out what you need.

Comment: A NOTE:  If the data spans multiple years, just add the year in there:  date("YW")

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have to give this a try, looks like it might work for what I need.

Comment: -1 Not a good idea to do this in the code when it can be done in the query. You are opening yourself up to an instant and severe performance hit.

Comment: @Kenaniah - the person asking the question specifically said "small site".   PHP is pretty capable of handling this kind of thing.  Further, the number of records could be limited by the query.  Not sure how your suggestion is any less of a potential performance hit if we were talking about millions of records.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin [WEEK() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) to get the week number.
You guys are over thinking it.

```
SELECT WEEK(myDate) AS wk, SUM(myInfo) As sumInfo FROM myTable GROUP BY WEEK(myDate) ORDER BY wk DESC
```

You can make it more advanced and **CONCAT(YEAR(myDate),'-',WEEK(myDate))** or overload WEEK() to specify the starting day in the week.